# How to link to a web page / URL and auto-populate text into the web form fields?

Tags: javascript, html, url, post

Firstly I am beginner with html, css, javascript and am just starting my journey to learn about web design and development.

I would like to auto-populate the form fields "Certificate Number" and "Candidate Number / Registration Number" on the below web page using a URL / link that I can use in an anchor element / on my own website.

https://eprofessional.bcs.org/Portal/eCertCheck

I have tried using query string parameters, which uses a GET method request and this does not work. MY understanding is that the server side has to support this for it to be able to work.

Example:

https://eprofessional.bcs.org/Portal/eCertCheck?CertificateNumber=12345&CandidateReferenceNumber=AA123456789

Using the Chrome Developer Tools I see that when the "Check" button is clicked, a POST request method is submitted to retrieve and verify a certificate.

**Payload**
btnLogin:
Check
CertificateNumber:
12345
CandidateReferenceNumber:
AA123456789
X-Requested-With:
XMLHttpRequest

Any help to point me in the right direction to be able to auto-populate the form fields so that a user just has to click the "Check" button OR to be able to populate the form fields AND to "click" the Check button to submit the form and display the result **would be greatly appreciated!**

Answer (score 1):

From what I see on the page you shared, the two input fields have the id `CertificateNumber` and `CandidateReferenceNumber`. In this case, to populate them you would have to take the elements by that ID and change their value to the URL one when the page loads.
I suggest you to take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams.

```
function populateFields(){
  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  const params = Object.fromEntries(urlSearchParams.entries());
  
  const certificateNumberField = document.getElementById("CertificateNumber")
  const candidateNumberField = document.getElementById("CandidateReferenceNumber")
  
  certificateNumberField.value = params.CertificateNumber
  candidateNumberField.value = params.CandidateReferenceNumber
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for reply @silvano-h I will look into URLSearchParams. As I am still learning could you provide some additional steps to incorporate the above into an anchor element URL from my website?

Comment: I do not understand what you're really trying to say, but if you want to set the anchor URL you can use the same logic I used in the code, by taking the anchor element by id and updating his HREF: linkElement.setAttribute("href", "whatever you want");